# if user_signed_in? puts some text - Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, puts

I have this idea that I want "Logged in" to be show in the upper corner of my webpage when `user_signed_in?` is true, but when `user_signed_in?` is false then I want it to only simply put "Login".

`user_signed_in?` is the helper method for Devise. I think.

How do I actually make this work. I tried this:

```
<%= if user_signed_in? => true puts "Logged In" else puts "Login" %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

This doesn't work though. Any ideas ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I hope my answer helped you.  If it did, please accept it (by clicking the check mark)! If not, let me know what you're still confused about by editing the question and I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should look into Ruby syntax a little more ([here](http://zetcode.com/lang/rubytutorial/flowcontrol/), for example).  Try this:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  Logged In
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Login', ... %> # substitute the ... for whatever path goes to login
<% end %>
```

Note that the <%= part is only used when the embedded ruby will actually be returning content that will be rendered by the browser (aka converted to html).  Since all your embedded ruby in your example is only control flow, don't use the =, since the browser won't actually see any of it.  However, the link_to method returns a link, which is actual rendered content, so we need the =.

Also note that since this is a view file--and thus is basically an enhanced html file--you don't need the "puts" for raw content like "Logged in".  In fact, puts wouldn't bring the content to the browser, but instead to wherever STDOUT leads in Rails apps (the logger? not sure)

Comment: I'll try this out, Thanks ;) I'll take a look athe control flow example zetcode thingy. I'll get back and tell you if it worked

Comment: Good luck! Rails syntax can get complicated since you're writing Ruby, Rails-enhanced Ruby, and html/embedded Ruby, so it can get overwhelming as a beginner. Stick with it and check out the multitude of great tutorials available online (and StackOverflow) and you'll get the hang of it.

Comment: @MarcusTheBuilder: You can find more helpers related to devise at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers

Comment: It worked terrifically. Thank you A LOT! :D Check-mark coming about wondering!